# How to sign into Azure AD B2C using only Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: xamarin.ios, azure-ad-b2c

Using plain Xamarin.iOS how do I sign into Azure AD B2C?

I know there is an example for Xamarin.Forms but I am unable to adapt it for Xamarin.iOS

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Microsoft Authentication](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client) Library (MSAL) in your mobile application to initiate an authentication workflow with your Azure Active Directory B2C tenant.

On the iOS platform, the `AppDelegate` class must be modified to initialize a `PlatformParameters` instance, as demonstrated in the following code example:

```cs
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App());

        var result = base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        App.AuthenticationClient.PlatformParameters = new PlatformParameters(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController);
        return result;
    }
}
```

The `PlatformParameters` instance is used by MSAL to recognize the platform on which it's running in order to select the platform-specific authentication user experience and token storage mechanism.

For more informatio [see documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/authentication/azure-ad-b2c/).

Comment: This uses Xamarin.Forms e.g. global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();  Im was not using Xamarin.Forms.